# jQuery: How can I highlight the element (such as add blue background color) when click this element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get the results that when I click one element in a web page, this element highlighted(e.g. its background color turn blue).I tried below,  In some time it can do it, but In other time it failed.  Have any other methods to solve?Thanks.

**elemselect.js**:

```
  var flag = null;
  jQuery(function ($) {
     $("*").bind("click", function () {
        if(flag)
         {
               $("*").removeClass("elemselected");
         }
        flag = $(this);

        $(this).addClass("elemselected");
        $(this).find("*").addClass("elemselected");
        return false;

});
```

**elemselect.css**:

```
.elemselected 
{
     border: #00BFFF solid thin;
     background-color: #00BFFF;
}
```

Comment: add html also or better jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toggleClass()`:

```
$('*').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("elemselected");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code, toggleClass("styleName") can handle your flag functionality.

```
$('*').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("elemselected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("*").click(function () {
$(".elemselected").removeClass("elemselected");
$(this).addClass("elemselected");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j3RtD/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).on('click', function(e){
        $('.elemselected').removeClass('elemselected');
        $(e.target).addClass('elemselected');
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2UjBx/)

Answer (score 0):

#### Check this <kbd>[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vZnH/371/)</kbd>

#### JQuery

```
$(".sel").on("click", function() {
    $(this).css("background", "red");
});
```

---

***Updated***

#### Check this <kbd>[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8UgT/656/)</kbd>

#### jQuery

```
  $('.sel').click( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("sel");
  });
```

Hope this both are help you!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried attr?

```
$('*').click(function() {
    $(this).attr("class":"elemselected");
});
```